# IntelliJ IDEA resolving web paths in JSP

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I set where IntelliJ looks for files referenced in a JSP? If I have

```
<jsp:include page="/foo/bar" />
```

it cannot resolve directory foo.

It looks like Settings > Web Contexts deals with this, but when I go there, it says

> No web directories found

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should configure a web facet in your project settings, then configure the directory containing `foo` as a "Web Resource Directory". If this is your root directory, set the "Path Relative to Deployment Root" to `/`.

See the [official doc](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-web-application-support.html) for more info.