# How do I resolve Spring model variables in a JSP when debugging with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, jsp, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've set a breakpoint in a JSP when running a Tomcat application through IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate ed.).  So far so good, I can step through the JSP as expected.

The problem is:  I am unable to resolve Spring model variables such as `${path}` when debugging.  *Evaluate Expression* triggers an error: "Cannot find variable 'path'".

As a workaround I can explicitly reference the model value with `<c:set var="testPath" value="${path}">`.  That way I can see `testPath` in **Variables » _jspx_page_context » attributes**, but not `path`.

Comment: Please add code as well.

Comment: Maybe you wanna have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878548/intellij-idea-resolving-web-paths-in-jsp

Comment: Try these 

1. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739/jsp-debugging-in-intellij-idea][1]

2. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694392/intellij-not-resolving-el-variables-within-jsp-code-inspection-or-autocomplete][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739/jsp-debugging-in-intellij-idea
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694392/intellij-not-resolving-el-variables-within-jsp-code-inspection-or-autocomplete

Comment: AdityaSingh &  @Saidolim:  None of those are relevant to my question, since I'm actually able to debug the JSP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variable `path` is part of the Spring Framework and is set as an attribute to the PageContext, there are only few ways of debbugging such variables.

For me the best solution is to add an expression to your Watches View: `pageContext.findAttribute("path")` or `_jspx_page_context.findAttribute("path")`

It doesn't matter, because both of them point to the same runtime object:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `pageContext` isn't available in my Variables view, but `_jspx_page_context` works fine.

Comment: @neu242 Ah ok, don't know that. Thought an pageContext is visible to all. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Nice answer! I had a similar need but using Eclipse rather than IntelliJ. This answer helped although it seems in Eclipse it seems even harder to get to the info (but fortunately still possible): Need to go to the Variables view and then expand  `_jspx_page_context - pageAttributes - table` and then open each mapped index individually and inspect the key/value for each.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a work-around, and is certainly not best practices. However, if you need something quick and dirty, set another String var to your $path param. The debugger will be able to see that new variable at runtime.